# Azure DevOps doesn't send Deployment approval

Tags: azure-devops

I have Deployment described as a code in the pipeline:

```
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      name: 'Self-Hosted'
    container: kagarlickij/packer-ansible-docker-runtime:1.1.0
    # creates an environment if it doesn't exist
    environment: 'sbx'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureCLI@1
            displayName: 'Create VM'
```

My Environment contains necessary approval:
[image]

Notifications are enabled in Project:
[image]

..and in my account:
[image]

Build, release and other notifications are working fine.

But I don't receive any emails when Deployment is initiated.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: Those alerts are for release definitions, not multistage pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Daniel said, the alerts are only available for release definitions (the traditional classic editor ones), they are not available for multistage pipelines (YAML ones).

There's already a ticket been submitted in Github : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/5687

According to the comments in the thread, this feature is being tracked as one of the critical gaps with Multi-stage YAML pipelines, and it may be implemented in the upcoming January release.

More information about the `Deployment approval`, please refer to [Define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass).